# How do theories within the natural sciences destabilize our view of the world?

Tags: epistemology

So, I've been thinking about this question as part of an assignment which I have to do and one way in which I have approached it is the following;

Our view of the world is essentially that pre-conceived idea of what physically happens based on what we can observe through the 5 senses. I'm working with this particular definition, at least for now.

Now, we can agree that a large part of constructing a scientific theory is observation.At the very least, that is what is clear within the inductivist view of science.

Naturally, because of this link to observation, I'm arguing that scientific theories destabilize our view of the world more than they solidify it, since they present details that we are not able to observe directly through our senses, thereby changing our understanding of what is actually happening in the world.

Would this argument actually work? If it does not, why?

EDIT:

So the original question was the following;

‘Every theory destabilizes as much as it solidifies our view of the world’’ (Nathan Jurgenson). Discuss.

I'm discussing this in the context of the human sciences and natural sciences

Comment: Are you arguing that "scientific theories let us create tools that enhance our senses"?

Comment: Are you arguing that "a person who has not been exposed to a certain scientific theory is likely to interpret a certain combination of sensations differently than a person who has been exposed to that scientific theory"?  This claim might be empirically verifiable.  You might be able to look up research papers that have attempted to verify or falsify it.

Comment: Maybe it's best to put this in terms of an example. So, without learning any theory in physics, we see that a ball will fall to the ground when it is released and a pendulum swings with a constant period. Now, from these sets of observations, as well as other mechanical examples, we can say that the world is deterministic. We obtained that from our senses. We study classical mechanics, a theory of physics, which is inherently deterministic. That is, you can always determine the future state of a system if you know enough about its current state.

Comment: Are you arguing that people's "confirmation bias" causes them to notice sensations that are consistent with accepted scientific theories, and dismiss sensations that are not consistent with those theories?  There is empirical evidence that babies expect "conservation of numbers of objects" (not types or masses of objects).  The evidence is that the babies pay *more* attention, not less attention when this "conservation law" is violated.

Comment: Please explain what "destabilizing our view of the world" means. Just changing it? Keep in mind "what we can observe through the 5 senses" is not everybody's view of the world. Many believe that reason and/or intellectual intuition are independent sources of information, and religious people also believe that revelation, etc. , is.  Moreover, observations are not a large part of constructing scientific theories, they barely play any constructive role at all, instead they *test* theories *after* they are constructed.

Comment: Now, a theory like quantum mechanics comes along and tells us that the world is inherently probabilistic. That, you can never truly think about trajectories in the same way as you did in classical mechanics. Now, I'm arguing that while that does not affect our senses directly, with the knowledge of quantum mechanics, we start to look at physical processes differently. That is, we perceive physical processes to be of a different nature than before, so our view of the world has essentially changed.

Comment: "A ball will fall to the ground when it is released".  And then it will bounce.  Which way will it bounce?  It is hard to predict which way an American football will bounce.

Comment: @Conifold, But see, here's the thing, it's not a matter of whether it is everybody's view of the world. It's the particular definition I am taking on to write the essay. It's not like I'm ignoring the fact that the view of the world changes depending on the perspective. It's just one particular definition of the view of the world that I am taking on. 

I'm taking destabilization, in the question, to mean that there is a shift in how we look at the world. Like, instead of looking at objects as being just particles, we think of them as being waves as well. Things like that.

Comment: Our sense of sight is directly affected by quantum mechanics.  In sufficiently low-light situations, our brains are capable of amplifying a signal from a single photon into an actionable observation.

Comment: @Jasper, of course it's hard to predict which way an American football will bounce. But it's not like it doesn't have a trajectory. It's not like it doesn't follow specific laws of physics. In principle, you could do it. It'd be very hard. I didn't say it will be easy. But it's possible to do it. 

In quantum theory, can you even think about trajectories? Can you even think about particles being just particles and not waves as well?

Comment: Based on their observations of things like balls bouncing, many people reach an opposite conclusion from you.  They conclude that "God" or "luck" or "Fate" or "the football gods" can influence how the ball bounces, and how the game turns out.

Comment: And so, when a theory comes along and makes a claim that it has predicted the motion of that football, with the evidence and the proofs etc etc., and when people accept that theory, their preconceived notions of what caused that ball to bounce, changes no?

Comment: Can you find historical examples of such "a theory com[ing] along"?  If so, you don't need a hypothetical.  If not, it is not a hypothetical worth discussing.

Comment: You say "scientific theories clearly do more to destabilize our view of the world". More than what? Because  science deals with what we can not directly observe, and only sensory observations count. Well, religion, art, etc., also often deal with what we can not directly (or ever) observe. Are you comparing science to them? I would think that any kind of practice "destabilizes" our views because they have to change as we refine it. Science is only one such practice.

Comment: @Jasper. Of course, the advent of theories like String Theory and Quantum Theory counted as theories which claimed to predict the behavior of particles which were appearing during the times in which they appeared.

Comment: @Conifold. I don't quite agree that science deals with what we cannot directly observe. Sure, it does do that but that's not all it does. Besides, perhaps I should have been clear in that I was referring our fundamental understanding of what happens in the world. When physicists solve the mystery behind Quantum Entanglement, that will be revolutionary but it won't change the fact that we believe that the world is inherently probabilistic, since that mystery will likely be solved using quantum mechanics itself.

Comment: What are the so-called "human sciences"?

Comment: http://www.theoryofknowledge.net/areas-of-knowledge/the-human-sciences/

This is how it's been defined as within the context of the course I'm doing. I'm not exactly in agreement with it but it's what I have to work with.

Comment: In other words, the "social sciences".  In this context, "social" means "not".

Comment: I think that, if one wishes to claim that theories "destabilize" our worldview, we must first start from the assumption that our worldview is wrong.  In that sense, you are correct, that the crowning achievement of science is the identification and rejection of worldviews that are inconsistent with empiricism.  And, of course, do remember that it stabilizes new theories in its wake.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I edited the question again. I'm really not in the best state right now, I made a really stupid mistake.

@CortAmmon, and if science stabilizes our view of the world, then our view of the world is going to be largely correct right? Because over here, I'm not talking about destabilization as a fine-tuning process, where we got one fact wrong but everything else is correct. Here, I'm talking about the fundamentals.

Comment: "Scientific theories destabilize our view of the world more than they solidify it, since they present details that we are not able to observe directly" are your own words. And those who believe in God claim that he is part of "our fundamental understanding of what happens in the world" as well (or deep emotions expressed in art, for that matter). I am feeling that you want the answer to be science, but I do not quite see a natural question to which it is the only answer. You seem to be imposing extra stipulations simply to make it so.

Comment: For this essay, I recommend avoiding the relationships between truly scientific theories (like gravity, valence shell electron pair repulsion theory, and quantum electrodynamics) and how people understand sensations.  Instead, think about how new ideas (regardless of whether they are more true or less true than older ideas) in the humanities cause people to doubt their understandings of how society "does" or "should" work.  Also, you might want to compare and contrast the prompting statement with the idea that "some ideas are more true than others".  Can both statements be true simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its trivial to argue that any theory does a combination of stabilizing and destabilizing worldviews.  Naturally, it stabilizes those parts of your world view which are consistent with the theory, and destabilizes those which are not.

To argue that it stabilizes more or destabilizes more, we need a way to compare these effects.  Finding a way to do that is not easy.  Sometimes it stabilizes more, such as when you've noticed some strange coincidence in our observations and you find out that there is a theory behind it.  Other times it destabilizes more, such as when you thought you knew everything and someone kicks the chair right out from underneath you (QM and relativity are notorious for that).

I don't know if you can say universally that theories destabilize more than stabilize.  If so, the most unstable people would be the ones who learned the most theories.  This concept of stabilization must be taken globally.  You are also destabilized when you cannot predict what is going to happen because you lack theories to do the prediction with.  A theory that destabilizes at first may stabilize in the long run.

I think avalanche breakdown in diodes may be an excellent example.  To understand avalanche breakdown you need to understand QM, because the effect involves quantum tunneling.  You may choose to view QM as a destabilizing theory if you please.  However, once you understand it, integrated circuits are a bit less magic.  So here's the question... which is more stable?  Having QM under your belt and understanding the theory behind avalance breakdown?  Or believing that IC's are simply magic?  It turns out that you can live quite the stable life believing that ICs are magic devices powered by smoke.  And that makes the decision really complicated.  Was your life destabilized by learning enough QM to take the magic out of ICs?